# Сортировка пользовательского класса в QVector

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Как сделать сортировку вектора моего класса `QVector <DbTrade>`?

Вот код:

*dbtrade.h:*

```
#ifndef DBTRADE_H
#define DBTRADE_H


class DbTrade
{
public:
    DbTrade();
    DbTrade(int tradenum, int dateTime, int price, int qty, int buysell, int openInterest);

    int getTradenum();
    int getDateTime();
    int getPrice();
    int getQty();
    int getBuysell();
    int getOpenInterest();

    void setTradenum(int tradenum);
    void setDateTime(int dateTime);
    void setPrice(int price);
    void setQty(int qty);
    void setBuysell(int buysell);
    void setOpenInterest(int openInterest);


private:

    int tradenum;
    int dateTime;
    int price;
    int qty;
    int buysell;
    int openInterest;

};

#endif // DBTRADE_H
#endif // DBTRADE_H
```

*dbtrade.cpp:*

```
#include "dbtrade.h"

DbTrade::DbTrade()
{
    tradenum = 0;
    dateTime = 0;
    price = 0;
    qty = 0;
    buysell = 0;
    openInterest = 0;
}

DbTrade::DbTrade(int tradenum, int dateTime, int price, int qty, int buysell, int openInterest)
{
    this->tradenum = tradenum;
    this->dateTime = dateTime;
    this->price = price;
    this->qty = qty;
    this->buysell = buysell;
    this->openInterest = openInterest;
}

int DbTrade::getTradenum()
{
    return tradenum;
}

int DbTrade::getDateTime()
{
    return dateTime;
}

int DbTrade::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

int DbTrade::getQty()
{
    return qty;
}

int DbTrade::getBuysell()
{
    return buysell;
}

int DbTrade::getOpenInterest()
{
    return openInterest;
}

void DbTrade::setTradenum(int tradenum)
{
    this->tradenum = tradenum;
}

void DbTrade::setDateTime(int dateTime)
{
    this->dateTime = dateTime;
}

void DbTrade::setPrice(int price)
{
    this->price = price;
}

void DbTrade::setQty(int qty)
{
    this->qty = qty;
}

void DbTrade::setBuysell(int buysell)
{
    this->buysell = buysell;
}

void DbTrade::setOpenInterest(int openInterest)
{
    this->openInterest = openInterest;
}
```

Далее, я в другом классе инициализирую вектор:

```
QVector <DbTrade> tradeVector;
```

и заполоняю его.

Но как его отсортировать по элементу `price`?

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь стандартным алгоритмом:

```
std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](const DbTrade& lha, const DbTrade& rha){
    return lha.getPrice() < rha.getPrice();
});
```

Только для этого вам понадобится конструктор копирования. Возможно, стоит хранить вектор указателей на `DbTrade`, чтобы не копировать лишний раз. Или еще лучше: `QVector<std::unique_ptr<DbTrade>>` - тогда не нужно заботиться об управлении памятью.

Comment: Спасибо очень помог